# Bind logs to applications

Tags: splunk

How does splunk tie logs to an application?

When using logback TCP appender to send logs to splunk, how does splunk tie the messages to an index or application?

Answer (score 0):

Splunk organizes data into [indexes](https://docs.splunk.com/Splexicon:Index) by [sourcetype](https://docs.splunk.com/Splexicon:Sourcetype).

When data is sent to Splunk (via [Universal Forwarder](https://docs.splunk.com/Splexicon:Universalforwarder), [HTTP Event Collector (HEC)](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Data/HECExamples), etc), it's tagged with what index and sourcetype it is so that it gets stored properly for later searching.